# Get Value from Button (Previous Window) then used it in new Window

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a system. So in my QT, I have 3 pages which are the main window, first dialog, second dialog. So I put some radio buttons and checkboxes in my firstdialog. In the second dialog, I plan to print the total out. I want users to pick where did they want this or not. If yes then the radios button or check button will receive the value and pass it into the second dialog. How can I do that? I am new to QT （C++) so if possible help me with providing some example codes with explanations. This is very appreciated!

Comment: Most likely you want to use signals and slots between your dialogs. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: I'm afraid SO is not a place you're looking for. The answer would have to  contain multiple source and header files with detailed explanation. You need a tutorial, not an SO answer.  Qt itself has plenty of superb documentation, example programs and tutorials. For example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/widgets-tutorial.html    https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html

Comment: Thanks, I change the way and I was able to solve this problem!